# Why doesn't linked question in a comment appear in linked question part?

Tags: bug, status-completed, linked-questions

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28429609/995714) sashoalm commented the link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230268/get-the-upper-half-of-the-eax-register) as a possible duplicate, but it doesn't appear in the *Linked* part like below.

[image: linked question]

Why is this?

Comment: The link in the comment uses the `https:` scheme. That may be the problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi correct, I verified this by adding a test comment with link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230268/get-the-upper-half-of-the-eax-register and it appeared in the Linked sidebar indeed. Worth posting this as answer. :)

Comment: Worth to mention, there is already a [pending bug report in MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https).

Comment: see details about the fix [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248385/156631)