# Why doesn't this linked question show in the "Linked" sidebar?

Tags: support, bug, linked-questions

[This question (15856587)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856587/greasemonkey-inject-xml-document) has had a link to [this related question (384639)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384639/how-to-include-javascript-in-xml-document) for two an a half years. And there is (now) only one other linked question (18046191).

Yet question 384639 does not appear in the ***Linked*** area of the sidebar:

[(Click for a larger view)

[image: Missing Link]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hcmW.png)

Why?  It's definitely not [this old bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285751/why-doesnt-linked-question-in-a-comment-appear-in-linked-question-part).

Comment: Here's another example:

Q1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346480/how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware

Q2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597790/can-i-set-largeaddressaware-from-within-visual-studio

An [Answer in Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20374198) links to Q2, but Q2 is neither shown in the *Linked* box in the sidebar nor in the [list of linked questions for Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1346480?sort=votes). The same is true for the sidebar and *Linked* box of Q2.

Comment: (For the case above) I posted a comment with a link to it and delete it immediately, and now that case is fixed, so I guess it's only a temporary database error. It doesn't work with the other cases however. The issue on that particular question can still be seen in the internet archive https://web.archive.org/web/20170413173103/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346480/how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware //// Given that that answer is posted before  the HTTP->HTTPS rewrite rule, I assume that the database is originally wrong because it was in HTTP.

Comment: ... or not. Back in 2013 when only HTTP links are linked https://web.archive.org/web/20141017101550/http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions/1346480/how-to-make-a-net-application-large-address-aware  / https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https it isn't linked as well.

Answer (score 3):

I have another example of the same issue.
Question [git ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203228/git-ignore-exception) has comment

> possible duplicate of [Exceptions in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415873/exceptions-in-gitignore) – wallyk ↵ Feb 27 '12
> at 9:26

but "Linked" sidebar doesn't show it as linked question.
The referred question [Exceptions in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415873/exceptions-in-gitignore) also doesn't have the first question as linked.

Another example: Question [How to read large text file on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846475/how-to-read-large-text-file-on-windows) has a comment

possible duplicate of [Best Free Text Editor Supporting *More Than* 4GB Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102829/best-free-text-editor-supporting-more-than-4gb-files) – nawfal ↵ Feb 26 '13 at 20:21

But the linked question not shown on right sidebar

Comment: I notice that in both these cases the link uses HTTP, not HTTPS.

Comment: Previously the situation was the reverse: [Questions don't link if the URL uses HTTPS - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226467/questions-dont-link-if-the-url-uses-https)